# Sharing spatiotemporal data on web using QGIS

Tags: qgis, netcdf, qgis2web, spatio-temporal-data, flood

I have NetCDF data of predicting the flood and need to show them in web map. I read (and also tried), plugin QGIS2WEB is not friendly with temporal data and Temporal Controller plugin.
Is there any way that I can make web map using these data in QGIS?

Comment: netCDF can be inserted into QGIS as a raster and qgis2web exports rasters correctly.  You need to do a test for the symbols.  Can you provide the file, or part of it, by uploading it to the web?  I think we can make a static map, but we would need to work on it if you want something interactive that shows the data changing over time.